# Use RSA to sign a license file

Tags: encryption, licensing, rsa

I've been trying to figure out a way of stopping people tampering with a license file that gets shipped with my software. I have been looking at RSA and using signing to verify the data.

Now from my understanding I basically have some data (the license file) and I use the RSACryptoServiceProvider's SignData method to create a signature for the data with a public and private key that was created via ExportParameters(true).

Then I would give the license file and the public key with the software so I can verify the data (license) on the client using VerifyData but what is to stop the user creating there own public/private key pair and recreating the data and just overwriting the public key and data?

I've been reading around and doing some googling but I'm still stuck with this, I'm fairly new to encryption and signing also but I need to figure this out.

I'm aware that it's virtually impossible to secure a license like file as if they wanted they could just decompile the code and remove the checks so I'm just wanting to make it harder for them to abuse the software, I don't want them to be able to just make up there own license or move one license to another machine.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or offer some advice?

Thank you.

Comment: I've looked into this myself, for licensing Java.  The client in my case wasn't willing to set up an activation server so my software could verify the license against it, so I had to take the encrypt / decrypt approach.  What I did was to encode the customer details in the license and expiration dates and volume limits, etc. to discourage copy of the license to other locations.  Still, if the customer understood Java, they could have replaced the classes that deal with product activation, but I can't easily prevent that - just make it harder.

Comment: I've also looked at this approach as well, encrypting a license file and decrypting it on the client. Where did you store the key? Did you embed it within the software or have it in a file?

Comment: I find activation servers offensive. In order to be able to run a certain piece of software, I have to continually run (and expend resources for) an unaudited network service that I am forbidden to scan for vulnerabilities that may be relevant to the security of my company network.

Comment: @Simon Richter, I agree, but the client requirement was a product activation system that prevented piracy.  I think that if the client had agreed to run a server, it would have simply been a 2-part activation process with some time component in the code to prevent it from being re-used.

Comment: I currently store the encrypted license in the DB and decrypt it each time the software is started.  Key is currently embedded in the software.  I'm not sure that keeping it separate gives much advantage.  Sure, you can vary the key you use, but this is easy to transport, along with the license code.  I'm open to better suggestions though - not that happy with the current solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing would stop them. The entire point of applying cryptography to software licensing is to create stronger evidence for use in a court.

Do not spend too much time on making your licencing system hard to circumvent (the more complicated it is, the more people will see it as a challenge), but rather ensure that your paying customers aren't hindered by it.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much my answer to my client.  I'm just not happy with my current solution because it doesn't meet the client's stated requirement.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I think I'll just make it so they can't easily give themselves full access to everything or move the license file to another machine.

I agree with Simons comment about the activation server aswell.

Comment: The difficulty with stopping people from moving licences to other machines is that it often also stops them from moving the licence to a new installation.